# Moq: Unable to cast object of type Castle.Proxies.IMessageProxy' to type 'MyProject.Message'

Tags: c#, casting, moq, mstest, xmlserializer

I have the following extension method to serialise an object into XML using the `XmlSerialiser` class:

```
public static string Serialise<T>(this T value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    {
        xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Since `XmlSerialiser` cannot serialise an interface type, I am casting the interface type to concrete type. This is a .NET Standard 1.3 project.

```
public void Submit(IMessage message)
{
    var xml = ((Message)message).Serialise();
}
```

Using `MsTest` and `Moq 4.8.1`, the following test fails with this message: `Unable to cast object of type Castle.Proxies.IMessageProxy' to type 'MyProject.Message'`

```
[TestMethod]
public void Submit()
{  
    var mockMessage = new Mock <IHospitalSendBatchMessage>();
    _service.Submit(mockMessage.Object);
}
```

I understand that I should not have to cast an interface to a concrete type but this is the quickest way to get the serializer working. Is there any way to mock the casting operation or another approach to solving this problem?

Comment: This is an implementation concern issue. Review your design choices.

Comment: I think the main issue is the extension method. I am currently experimenting with a serialiser class instead of using an extension method, which can be mocked easily.

Comment: Yes that is the better approach to take as static members tend to make unit testing difficult

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain what is the bigger picture and maybe a more targeted answer can be provided.